# powershell delete some files older than 90 days, with exceptions

Tags: powershell

```
$timeLimit1 = Get-Date.AddDays(-90)
Get-ChildItem <path> | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -le $timeLimit1 } | Remove-Item
```

So I have the easier part, but I am trying to figure out how to do something a little more complex.

I am setting up a backup deletion routine.  The requirement is to keep the last 90 days of backups, then the final day of each month prior to that for the current year and finally a backup from December 31st for the prior 2 years.

I couldn't find any examples other than just a single check; is it possible to do several checks to automate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest writing a custom filter to apply the logic e.g.

```
filter MyCustomFilter{

    $File = $_

    $FileDate = $File.LastWriteTime
    $Now = (Get-Date)
    $FileAgeDays = ($Now - $FileDate).TotalDays

    if (

        # Keep files for at least 90 days
        ( $FileAgeDays -lt 91 
        ) -or

        # Keep files from last day of the month this year
        (  $FileDate.Year -eq $Now.Year -and
           $FileDate.Month -ne $FileDate.AddDays(1).Month
        ) -or

        # Keep files from 31 Dec for up to 2 years
        (   $FileAgeDays -lt ( 2 * 365 ) -and
            $FileDate.Month -eq 12 -and 
            $FileDate.Day -eq 31
        )

    ) { 

        # File should be kept, so nothing is returned by the filter

    } else { 

        # File should be deleted, so pass the file down the pipeline
        write-output $File

    }


}
```

Now your overall code would look something like this:

```
get-childItem -path <path> |
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    MyCustomFilter |
    Remove-Item
```

It goes without saying, that proper testing is required before letting this loose on production systems.

EDIT: A Simpler test for last day of month

I thought of a neater 'last day of the month' test, which is simply to compare the `month` property of the date under test, with the `month` property of the following day e.g.

```
$FileDate.Month -ne $FileDate.AddDays(1).Month
```

will return `$true` if `$FileDate` is last day of the month.

Comment: nice job I will give this a try

Comment: There was a mistake in the `else` section. Now fixed.

Comment: Updated the 'last day of the month' test.

Answer (score -1):

Just create an array of your "special" dates and add them to your filter.

```
$timeLimit1 = Get-Date
$timeLimit1.AddDays(-90)
$specialDates = (Get-Date "31-12-2014"), (Get-Date "31-05-2017") # continue the list 
Get-ChildItem <path> | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -le $timeLimit1 -and $specialDates -notcontains $_.LastAccessTime.Date } | Remove-Item
```

I would also make a function to find the "special" dates.

Comment: It's common courtesy to leave a comment when you downvote.